# How do you Manipulate two dates within 'some View' in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to compare a date with todays date to see if it's in the past - and then add a year to it if it is. I've seen people do this in Xcode Playground projects but if I try to implement it within a 'some View' it comes up with the error message "No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'"

I first tried it with the original data, but I got confused with the bindings:

```
struct DatesView: View {
    @Binding var dates: [DatesInfo] 
    let nowDate = Date()
    @State private var dateComponent = DateComponents()

    var sortedDates: [DatesInfo] {
        dates.sorted {
            $0.date < $1.date
        }
    } 


    var body: some View {

        ForEach($dates, id: \.id) { thing in
            if (nowDate.timeIntervalSince1970 > thing.date.timeIntervalSince1970) {
                if thing.reccuring{
                    dateComponent.year = 1
                    let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: thing.date)
                    thing.date = futureDate
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

(The error was occurring on the `dateComponent.year = 1` line)

I did get further by trying to use the sorted list of dates (`sortedDates`) but the error was still occurring and I don't know how I would get it to update the date for the original data

Comment: Move your pure swift code to a function or computed property, a view should contain code for UI components and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of elements that you need to understand to make your code work.

As mentioned you need to have computation code into functions and/or "special" places in SwiftUI.
For example `.onAppear{...}`. The `body` of a `View` is for displaying other views,
such as a `Text(...)` view, as shown in the example code.

In addition, because your `DatesInfo` structs are in an array (dates: [DatesInfo]), you
need to use the index of the particular `DatesInfo` if you want to change its value.

I suggest you read the basics of SwiftUI, see for example: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Here is some example code to get you going in manipulating two dates in a View in SwiftUI.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dates = [DatesInfo(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(-234567), reccuring: true),
                       DatesInfo(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(234567), reccuring: true)]
    
    var body: some View {
        DatesView(dates: $dates)
    }
}

struct DatesView: View {
    @Binding var dates: [DatesInfo]
    let nowDate = Date()
    
    var sortedDates: [DatesInfo] {
        dates.sorted { $0.date < $1.date }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(sortedDates) { thing in
            Text("\(thing.date)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            updateDates()
        }
    }
    
    func updateDates() {
        for i in dates.indices {
            if (nowDate.timeIntervalSince1970 > dates[i].date.timeIntervalSince1970) {
                if dates[i].reccuring,
                   let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: dates[i].date) {
                    dates[i].date = newDate
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DatesInfo: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var date: Date
    var reccuring: Bool
}
```